# Signal goroutines to stop with channel close

Tags: go, channel

I have got multiple goroutines that `select` from two channels: one chan provides data, one chan for signals (kind of done/quit channel).

I use the signals channel to capture signals (kill) and gracefully close the goroutines.

I'm running the 'worker' goroutines from `package a`, while the goroutine func that captures signals runs from `package b`.

I use the signals package from https://gist.github.com/reiki4040/be3705f307d3cd136e85.

```
package a

import "sync"

WorkChan := make(chan int)
QuitChan := make(chan struct{})

func Stop() {
        fmt.Println("Stop called, closing channel")
        close(QuitChan)
}

func Work(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    var item int
    for {
        select {
        case item = <- WorkChan:
            ... processing
        case <- QuitChan:
            wg.Done()
            return
        }
    }
}
```

The goroutine to catch signals, and call `a.Stop()`

```
package b

import (
    "os/signal"
    "os"
    "syscal"
    "a"
)

func Signal() {

    sChan := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(signalChan, syscall.SIGTERM, syscall.SIGINT)

    for {
        s := <-sChan
        switch s {
        case os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM:
            a.Stop()
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my main func

```
package main

import (
    "a"
    "b"
    "sync"
)

func main() {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    go b.Signal()

    wg.Add(1) // for simplicity; actual code start multiple goroutines of Work
    go a.Work(&wg)

    // wait until work is done
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Done.")
}
```

When I kill the running process, I see the printed message from `Quit`. I expected that once the channel is closed, the goroutines will `select` the `QuitChan` case at some point and return.

But they keep running; they continue to process items from `WorkChan`. seems like it is ignored. What am I missing here?
Doesn't the channel get closed? How come it is still open?

Comment: Can you also post `a.Quit()`? Or is that `a.Stop()`?

Comment: @icza It's a.Stop(), thanks. I updated the question

Comment: When you close `a.QuitChan`, that will terminate `a`'s goroutine (sooner or later), but the goroutine in the `b` package has no termination condition, that will run forever. Also, the app will not terminate just because some "random" goroutine ended, the app terminates when the `main` goroutine ends (we don't know what your `main` goroutine is).

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "they keep running"?

Comment: You have a loop in `b`'s goroutine, and there is no return nor break statement in it, so it will run forever. A goroutine or its loop will not magically end or return just because an independent goroutine ended.

Comment: @icza I’m ok with goroutines in b keep running. My problem is goroutines in A doesn’t get stop (returned) and they keep running - processing more items from WorkChan. That’s what I’m trying to ahieve

Comment: Just because you see `"Stop called, closing channel"` printed, that is not guarantee that the `QuitChan` is closed (as the print is before the `close()` call). Put a print statement _after_ the `close()` and confirm if you see that printed.

Comment: Also, the code you posted is obviously just a fragment. You used short variable declaration: `QuitChan := make(chan struct{})`, and there is also a chance you shadowed a potential global `QuitChan` variable, and you may be closing a different channel. This is not possible to tell based on the fragments we see. Would be best if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: @icza I had to fragment it, else it would be too long. I tried to pin point what I'm seeing vs expecting. I'll try with print statement after the close statement to verify it is called and double check there is no shadowing issue

Comment: @icza I've updated the question; hopefully it is more complete now, with the main func included. I've double checked - no shadowing. I'll be able to verify the print after close call tomorrow

Comment: You are copying the WaitGroup. Use a pointer instead. `go vet` should complain about that, I think.

Comment: In your last comment you said you get an error that the channel is already closed. This confirms my suspicion that you shadow the global variable. We don't see your exact code, and I understand that would be too long. Again, please post a [mcve] as we are just wasting each others' time. As it is now, this question is off-topic.

Answer (score 6):

**First I think you should make a simple test, and past it out. It will be more help to let other understand what's your problem.**

I changed your code, and make it reading like a go code, instead of other language. **Now it's worked**.

In your code, there are some mistakes, I marked it as ERROR comment. Some are grammar error, like creating `WorkChan`. Some are type error.

One import design thing you should know, when you want exit after execute `Stop()`, you should close the `WorkChan` where you send data to `WorkChan`, insteal of just return at where you receive date.

- a.go

  ```
  package a

  import (
      "fmt"
      "sync"
  )

  // ERROR: can not do make in global
  var WorkChan chan int
  var QuitChan chan struct{}

  // Create chan when init
  func init() {
      fmt.Println("Init a")
      WorkChan = make(chan int)
      QuitChan = make(chan struct{})
  }

  func Stop() {
      fmt.Println("Stop called, closing quit channel")
      close(QuitChan)
  }

  // Close the work channel where you send date
  func Start(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
      i := 0
      for {
          select {
          case <-QuitChan:
              fmt.Println("Closing work chan")
              close(WorkChan)
              wg.Done()
              return
          default:
              WorkChan <- i
              i++
          }
      }
  }

  // Work will exit when workchan closed
  func Work(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
      for item := range WorkChan {
          fmt.Printf("Receive %d\n", item)
      }
      wg.Done()
      fmt.Println("Work exit")
  }
  ```
- b.go

  ```
  package b

  import (
      "github.com/shitaibin/awesome/a"
      "os"
      "os/signal"
      "syscall"
  )

  func Signal() {

      sChan := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
      signal.Notify(sChan, syscall.SIGTERM, syscall.SIGINT) // ERROR

      for {
          s := <-sChan
          switch s {
          case os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM:
              a.Stop()
              return // should return free resource
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- main.go

  ```
  package main

  import (
      "fmt"
      "github.com/shitaibin/awesome/a"
      "github.com/shitaibin/awesome/b"
      "sync"
  )

  func main() {

      var wg sync.WaitGroup

      go b.Signal()

      wg.Add(1)      // for simplicity; actual code start multiple goroutines of Work
      go a.Work(&wg) // ERROR: pointer

      wg.Add(1)
      go a.Start(&wg) // Send data and close channel when stop

      // wait until work is done
      wg.Wait()
      fmt.Println("Done.")
  }
  ```
- Result

  ```
  // omit
  Receive 87028
  Receive 87029
  Receive 87030
  Receive 87031
  Receive 87032
  Receiv^C101    <---- send signal here
  Receive 87102
  Receive 87103
  Receive 87104
  Receive 87105
  Receive 87106
  Receive 87107
  Receive 87108
  Receive 87109
  Receive 87110
  Stop called, closing quit channel
  Receive 87111
  Receive 87112
  Closing work chan
  Work exit
  Done.
  ```

Comment: I'm already using &wg so that wasn't the issue, but I did made some progress after moving the channel initialization into a function. I declare QuitChan in global scope, init it in Start(), but when I close it now I get `panic: close of nil channel`